# Change of Variables in Laplacian

Tags: calculus, coordinate-systems

I know how to prove $$\nabla^2(\frac{1}{r}) = -4\pi\delta^3(\textbf{r}),$$ where in Spherical coordinates, $$ \nabla^2 = {\frac{1}{r^2} \, \frac{\partial}{\partial r} \left( r^2 \, \frac{\partial}{\partial r} \right)} + \frac{1}{r^2 \sin\theta} \, \frac{\partial}{\partial\theta} \left( \sin\theta \,\frac{\partial}{\partial \theta}  \right) + \frac{1}{r^2 \sin^2\theta} \, \frac{\partial^2}{\partial\phi^2}.$$

Similarly when I try to prove $$\nabla^2(\frac{1}{R}) = -4\pi\delta^3(\textbf{R}),$$ where $$R=|\textbf{R}|=|\textbf{r} - \textbf{r}'|,$$ I need to write down the Laplacian $\nabla^2$ in terms of $R$. How can I explicitly show this?

Answer (score 0):

Note the following

\begin{eqnarray*}
\partial _{\mathbf{x}}\frac{1}{R} &=&\partial _{\mathbf{x}}\frac{1}{|\mathbf{
x-y}|} \\
\frac{\partial }{\partial _{x_{k}}}\frac{1}{|\mathbf{x-y}|} &=&\frac{
\partial (x_{k}-y_{k})}{\partial _{x_{k}}}\frac{\partial }{\partial
(x_{k}-y_{k})}\frac{1}{|\mathbf{x-y}|}=\frac{\partial }{\partial R_{k}}\frac{
1}{R} \\
\frac{\partial }{\partial _{x_{k}}}\frac{\partial }{\partial R_{k}}\frac{1}{R
} &=&\frac{\partial (x_{k}-y_{k})}{\partial _{x_{k}}}\frac{\partial }{
\partial (x_{k}-y_{k})}\frac{\partial }{\partial R_{k}}\frac{1}{R}=\frac{
\partial }{\partial R_{k}}\frac{\partial }{\partial R_{k}}\frac{1}{R}
\end{eqnarray*}
Thus
\begin{equation*}
\partial _{\mathbf{x}}^{2}\frac{1}{R}=\partial _{\mathbf{R}}^{2}\frac{1}{R}%
=-4\pi \delta ^{3}(\mathbf{R})
\end{equation*}